# VScode doesn't use the kivy file

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, kivy

I'm new to programming and trying to use Kivy to create a simple game.
I am following a tutorial, and I'm using VSCode, but I can't understand why the code I write in the `.kv`file doesn't is used by the `main.py`file.

I have two files in the directory.

1. main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget



class MainWidget(Widget):
    pass

class TheLabApp(App):
    pass

TheLabApp().run()
```

2. thelab.kv

```
MainWidget:


<MainWidget>:
    Button:
        text: 'Hello'
        size: 400, 200
```

I have installed a Kivy extension, and of course the Kivy module. But when I run the code the only thing that appears is a black screen, without the button.
What is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It is required to save the .kv file before running the code, it is just such a sily thing, but if it isn't saved it is read like if it was empty, or never changed.